# Automatically hide labels in line chart if cell is blank - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, linechart, vba

I have a simple line chart that plots data from a given cell range automatically. The data changes dynamically, and leaves some blanks some blanks cell within the range. I would like to the line chart to only plot cells that have values in it.

I already wrote a #N/A function so it wont chart the cell as 0. I want to know, how do I remove the label segments, so that only cells with value will be charted? And how can I make this solution dynamic so when those N/A cells have data they will be charted too?

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: Check out [this site](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-suppress-0-values-in-an-excel-chart/), try the formatting option first (on the `0` cells, use the custom style `0,0;;;`. If that doesn't work, try via the Options menu. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a different range for the X axis labels. Create a formula that returns the label text only when there is a number in the value column. Then use that range for the x axis labels. Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

The formula in the third column is `=IF(ISNUMBER(B2),A2,"")`. This formula will return the text from the first column only if the value column contains a number. If the cell is blank or contains the #N/A error, then a blank will be returned.

Then edit the data source, click the "Edit" button in the section for the X axis labels and select the third column instead of the first.

If you only want to chart the rows where there is a value, look into dynamic charts with range names. Jon Peltier has a tutorial on [his site](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/DynamicColumnChart1.html), which I don't want to repeat here.

Comment: Would there be a way to remove the two blank columns at the end of the graph? I know I can do it manually by unselecting "blanks", but is there a way for those blanks columns to be removed when they blank and then reappear when there is data to chart?

Comment: Your question is about hiding the labels and has been answered. Please mark the answer. I edited my answer to address your new question, but that should really be a new post.